# How to find the area/volume of a can?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

I'm doing some area work and I was wondering how find the area of a can... It's like finding the area of a cylinder right? I'm really confused. I just need the formulae... thanks

Comment: do you need to find the surface area first or something?

Comment: Yes, when the exercise says can, it means cylinder. Do you know the formulas for surface area and volume of a cylinder?

Comment: What is the area of the side (a rectangle)? What is the area of top/bottom (circles)?

Answer (score 2):

The post makes it quite clear that you only want the formulas. But let us *derive* the answer, from probably familiar facts about the area and circumference of a circle.

You know that a circle of radius $r$ has area $\pi r^2$ and circumference $2\pi r$.

Take your can. With a can opener, remove the top and bottom of the can. Each of these has area $\pi r^2$, for a combined area of $2\pi r^2$.

Now take tin shears, and *cut* the now topless and bottomless can, in a straight line from top to bottom. Separate at the cut, and flatten out the material of the can. You get a rectangle of height $h$, the height of the can. The width of the rectangle is the circumference of the original top (or bottom). So the rectangle has area $2\pi r h$.

Thus altogether the surface area of the original can is $2\pi r^2+2\pi r h$.

Answer (score 1):

Surface area(consisting of the area of two disks at the top and bottom and the side area): $ 2 \pi r^2 + 2 \pi r h$

Volume: $\pi r^2 h$

Enough?

Actually first Google result would give you these.

Comment: i know, thanks though

Comment: @user69933 Is this not what you were looking for?